# Есть ли разница между включением и перезапуском виртуального сервера, если до этого он был выключен?

Tags: виртуальная-машина, windows-server-2012

Что то, что другое, включает машину одинаково?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, одинаково..

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю данная информация должна быть предоставлена в описание power и provisioning состояний данного облачного провайдеры. Как пример в Ажуре, когда машина уже запущена на хосте, "перезапуск" рестартанёт её на том же железе.

Если вы остановите её через Портал, то машина будет "удалена" c текущего нода и ее образ отправлен для хранения. При следующем запуске/старте, машина запустится на новом железе.

Также не понятно, что вы подразумеваете под состоянием "выключена"? Есть 2 варианта как минимум, когда вы выключате саму машину, но она при этом запущена на хосте. Или вариант, когда вы ее выключаете и сносите с хоста.

Здесь пример описания из Ажура:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/virtual-machines/states-billing

https://stefanos.cloud/blog/azure-vm-power-states-and-provisioning-states/